# Give Android 2.3.3 Look And Feel to Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

When I run my application on Android 2.3.3 then it show different look and feel to android 4.0. When I run my application in Android 4.0, I want it to have the same look and feel as Android 2.3.3.

There are already a lot of questions asked on this topic but all the questions are "How to give higher version look and feel to lower version". But in my case I want to give lower version Look And Feel to higher version.

There is one solution which is, if I compile my application with Android 2.3.3 and run on Android 4.0 then it give Android 2.3.3 Look And Feel. But here I am not able to add features from Android 4.0, so this option is not a right way to achieve my goal.
So what I need to do?

Here I am attaching Look And Feel which I want:

[image]

But instead of above Look And Feel it show following look And Feel on Android 4.0

[image]

Comment: http://android-holo-colors.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Application's theme to `@android:style/Theme` in your app's manifest.

For example:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme" >
```

This will set your Application's Theme to the former default Android theme, which has been replaced by Holo in newer versions of Android. 
You can also select the DeviceDefault theme in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `targetSdkVersion` is set to a value of 10 or lower, and that your application does not declare a theme based on `Holo` when running on newer versions.  This will keep the `Holo` theme elements from being applied on newer devices.

Comment: So in the theme what I need to select ...Holo Dark, Holo Light or Holo Light with Dark Action Bar???